# What does this mean and is it correct to say so?

Tags: question-words

I have a text in english, the context is about electronics.

this is a sentence :

This work has a unique perspective based on the wind farm participation, through inertia control.

1- perspective based on something

2-perspective through something

are these sentences above correct in the whole sentence I wrote?

Also, I don't know what it is supposed to mean, I'm a translator not Electronic engineer.

Comment: I assumed from the florid language that it was describing some kind of installation art, not an engineering project ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It's an awkward sentence for sure, though I would personally read it as:

> This work has a unique perspective thanks to the wind farm participation...

That being said, I'm not sure "through inertia control" fits into any interpretation. Perhaps they mean something like:

> This work has a unique perspective thanks to the wind farm participation, which utilised [our] inertia control [technology].

But you'll have to check the context for what they mean by this.

Comment: It makes sense if "through inertia control" describes the participation. But it's hard to see exactly how that fits (you can participate through Microsoft Teams, but can you through inertia control?). More context would be useful.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps the person who originally wrote it didn't understand English well.  Work cannot have a unique perspective.  The person performing the work might, or the work might have given someone a unique perspective, but work is inanimate.

I have experience sizing servo systems, specifically keeping inertia in mind, so the last part of the sentence kind of makes sense.  It sounds like they're trying to say that "Through inertia control, we offer a unique perspective on wind farm applications."

That's a guess, though.

Comment: Work that expresses human ideas or meanings can have a perspective.